# How can I use a Linux shell pipe to rename a file?

Tags: shell

I would like to use a shell command line with a pipe to rename a file.

Example: renaming `x111.png` to `my_x111.png` (for each file, adding a prefix, 'my_')

I know `mv xxx bbb` is the best way to rename xxx to bbb, but how can I write the command in the shell?

Comment: Why do you need a pipe? `for file in *; do mv "$file" my_"$file"; done`

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f | awk '{printf "mv %s my_%s\n", $2, $2}' FS=/ | sh
```

Example

```
mv README my_README
mv tree.pl my_tree.pl
mv youtube.sh my_youtube.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
ls -1 *.png | nawk '{p=$0;$0="my_"$0;;system("mv "p" "$0); }'
```

A reference is [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/search/label/rename).

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/([^my_])(.*)/my_$1/g' *
```

This commands prepends all filenames with `my_` excluding the filenames that already start with `my_`.

This does depend on your version of `rename`, this requires the perl-version rather than the util-linux-ng one.

Comment: That regex looks wrong: `/([^my_])(.*)/` will find a file that has one char that is not an `m` or a `y` or a `_`. the file "my_foo" *will* be matched. Also, `$1` is the *first* set of matching parentheses, so the single character that's not `m|y|_`. You might want: `rename 'substr($_,0,3) != "my_" and $_ = "my_$_"' *`